# Does this cubic vertex-transitive graph have a name?

Tags: graph-theory

The graph depicted below arises as a special case in a paper of ours. Among other things, one can obtain it from the double generalised Petersen graph family, DP(6,1), but we suspect it is known from some other context as well. Did anyone come across it?

[image: DP(6,1)]

If it helps, here is graph6 string:

```
WhEKA?_C?O?_?P?g?I?@O?D?AG??C??AC??`??CG??O_??p
```

Any comment is most welcome!

Comment: You might try searching House of Graphs to see if anything is known about it there: https://hog.grinvin.org/SearchGraph.action

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo I just tried and it's not there. https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=1234 is the only bipartite cubic graph on 24 vertices with girth 6, and it has the wrong diameter.

Comment: Thank you @GregoryJ.Puleo for suggestion! I also just checked; and added graph6 string to the question.

Comment: In Mathematica's `GraphData` database, this graph goes by the uninformative name `{"CubicTransitive",38}`.

Comment: I tried to look if Mathematica's GraphData database is based on some known census; with no luck :(
But thank you; I didn't even consider that it is vertex-transitive!

Comment: The page https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicVertex-TransitiveGraph.html seems to suggest that it comes from Reed and Wilson's *Atlas of Graphs*, but I don't have a copy to check.

Comment: Thank you, I think I already have pretty sufficient answer! 
The name which arises from Reed and Wilson's _Atlas of Graphs_ seems to be *Ct38*, and perhaps more importantly, it is a bipartite double cover of the Durer graph, which very much explains its properties! Thank you for the constructive discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A community wiki summary of the discussion in the comments, for posterity:

The graph in the question is the [bipartite double cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_double_cover) of the [Dürer graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%BCrer_graph) shown below:

[image]

That is, for each vertex $v_i$ of the Dürer graph, we create vertices $u_i, w_i$, and for every edge $v_iv_j$ of the Dürer graph, we create edges $u_iw_j$ and $w_iu_j$.

In [Reed and Wilson's *Atlas of Graphs*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019853289X), small cubic vertex-transitive graphs are enumerated, and this one is given the name *Ct38*. Mathematica has this graph in its database as `GraphData[{"CubicTransitive", 38}]` and its graph6 string is:

```
WhEKA?_C?O?_?P?g?I?@O?D?AG??C??AC??`??CG??O_??p
```

---

The Dürer graph and its bipartite double cover are now in the House of Graphs as [graph 34383](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/34383) and [graph 34385](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/34385) respectively.

Comment: I saw this, and was going to tell him that the Reed and Wilson's just numbered them in some order.  Thanks for including the link.